# Using the Chakra-UI useDisclosure hook on both a parent and child component

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am trying to use the [Chakra UI useDisclosure hook](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-disclosure) accross two different components.  Basically, I have a parent component with a button and a child component with a different button.  I want to use `onToggle` in the parent component and `onClose` in the child component -- and have BOTH OF THEM control the state of `isOpen` on the child component.  Is this possible?  If so, how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the hook `useDisclosure` inside the parent component, then pass the state `isOpen` and `onClose` to your child component:

```
function Parent() {
  const { isOpen, onToggle, onClose } = useDisclosure()

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onToggle}>Open Drawer</Button>
      <Child isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose} /> 
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question doesn't directly relate to `Modal`, but if you're inside a `Modal` you can `useModalContext` to get the disclosure methods.

```
import { useModalContext } from '@chakra-ui/react';
const { isOpen, onClose } = useModalContext();
```